# Inner Class Intellij IDEA error not shown

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Could you please tell me why IDEA doesn't show any errors for the following. Is this syntax correct ?. When I try to compile, it displays the error message `Error:(24, 37) java: '(' expected`

```
public class Outer {
    class Inner {
        Inner() {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
}

class TestLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outer o = new Outer();
    Outer.Inner oi = o.new Outer.Inner(); //This is the line in question

    //write way to do it as I know of
    //Outer.Inner oi = o.new Inner();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Inner` class is package private, is your `TestLine` class in the same package?

Comment: o.new Outer ? Looks weird.

Comment: @Lino I just included both classes in the same file as above. So they are essentially in the same package.

Comment: @mate00 yes it is. It doesnt look correct. But why IDEA not showing any errors.

Comment: @mate00 that is the intended way of instantiating an inner class, with the outer class reference

Comment: @Lino I have seen only the `o.new Inner()` version as of now

Comment: @Isuru you're just qualiyfing the inner class with the outer, it's similar as when you'd write the package for a class, like: `java.lang.String s = "foo"`. A real life example of this is `Map.Entry` which I see very often

Comment: @Lino I guess I have to review some Java basics then. :)

Comment: @Lino that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA shows a correct error for me, and offers a quick fix to automatically fix the code. I think you are probably running an older version of IntelliJ IDEA. It appears [the issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192201) was fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.

[image: "Qualified class reference is not allowed in qualified new" error highlighting]

Comment: I haven't check the updated version yet. But I think you are right. I'm using IDEA version 2018.3.1. I will confirm once I updated my version.